# Constexpr and templates: compiler bug?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

The following works as expected:

```
#include <array>
constexpr std::array<int, 3> values = {1, 2, 3};
template <int i> struct A { static constexpr int val = values[i]; };
int main() { A<1> a; }
```

However, I get a compiler error from the MSVC compiler if we use `values.size()` as template parameter:

```
int main() { A<values.size()> a; }
```

The error is *expression did not evaluate to a constant*. The GCC compiles without error.

- Is this a bug of the MSVC compiler?
- Is there a standard/clever workaround to circumvent this bug?

Comment: Which version of MSVC?

Comment: Version "x64 msvc v19.16", see https://godbolt.org/z/fwpIAH

Comment: the workaround is trivial, no? `int main() { A<3> a; }`

Comment: btw I would maybe change the title, there is no single compiler bug here, so why "another" ?  ;)

Comment: I changed the title. Since GCC does compile and MSVC does not, "compiler bug?" seems appropiate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSVC is right. There cannot be undefined behaviour in any constexpr context. Or else this is not a constant expression.

The line:

```
int main() { A<values.size()> a; }
```

Is basically:

```
constexpr auto i = values[values.size()];
```

Which is out of bound. In fact, MSVC correctly diagnose the error:

> ```
> example.cpp
> <source>(3): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
> C:/msvc/v19_16/include\array(187): note: failure was caused by out of range index 3; allowed range is 0 <= index < 3
> <source>(4): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<3>' being compiled 
> <source>(2): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<int,3>' being compiled
> Compiler returned: 2
> ```

On the other hand, both GCC and MSVC accept this code:

```
int main() { A<values.size() - 1> a; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug/flaw of GCC, not MSVC.

```
A<values.size()> a;
```

causes you to access `values` out of range since the valid indexes are `[0, size())`.  MSVC gives you an error that it can't do that because it is undefined behavior, and that isn't allowed in a constant expression.

Note that clang also diagnoses this correctly and issues an error: https://godbolt.org/z/vmi86S